# Using private endpoint to access a blob storage account in Azure returns 403

Tags: azure, networking, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-network, azure-webapps

As seen below I want to put public network access Disabled on a storage account that contains blobs, then have a C# application on a VM access it via a private endpoint configured for blob access.
The VM and the Private Endpoint are both hosted in the same virtual network in one region, while the storage account is hosted in the same region but not on the virtual network.

I have enabled telemetry on the storage account and I am currently getting a 403 status code returned from the storage account with a status text of: "AuthorizationFailure" for any type of operation, I have tried with Operations: ListBlobs, ListContainers and more(but ListBlobs should at least be okay when the private endpoint is created for Blob). See in the bottom for the code I am using to access the storage account.
If I put Networking in the storage account to allow traffic from all networks then everything works just fine.

[image: Telemetry from storage account]

My main theory is that my private endpoint is not being used at all, but when I read about private endpoints created for storage accounts then you don't have to change the connection string, it should just automatically sent the traffic through the private endpoint. I have been trying to enable diagnostics on the private endpoint to see if any traffic is entering, but I am not 100% sure that I am looking in the right place, see picture below from Insights -> Show Metrics Pane:
[image: Telemetry]

I was looking at this tutorial on how to troubleshoot connectivity issues on private endpoints:
[=private-link/troubleshoot-private-endpoint-connectivity=x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/troubleshoot-private-endpoint-connectivity?WT.mc_id=Portal-fx)
And it says that my use-case should be supported:
`Virtual network from the same region`

Code I use to access the storage account:

```
    private static void connectToUS2StorageAccount()
{
    var herp = new BlobServiceClient("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccountus2x;AccountKey=<AccountKey>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
    var blobs = herp.FindBlobsByTags("k1=v1");
    foreach(var blob in blobs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Blob name:{blob.BlobName}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"-----");
}
```

General settings for the storage account:

[image: General settings for the storage account]

Comment: Try to Confirm that the VM's managed identity is assigned the Storage Blob Data Contributor role on the storage account and ensure the private endpoint is connected to the VM's virtual network within the same region. Verify that the network settings permit the virtual network to access the storage account. @DenLilleMand

Comment: @VinayB Yeah I kind of got past my issue, instead of the VM I created a web app. Both the VM and the Web App are integrated in the same vNet, but for some reason the web app picks up the private DNS Zone record that points the connection string to the private endpoint while the VM goes to look at the public DNS Records and hits the public endpoint of the storage account. I thought that if a VM was a part of a virtual network then it would automatically pick up a private DNS zone linked to that vnet, but this doesn't happen for me, maybe firewall issue or similar.